# Nano save to stdout (or an inline editor for terminal)

Tags: command-line, bash, editor, scripts

Is there a way of saving nano to stdout? Or an inline editor for terminal?

I mean, I would like to do things as for example, editing an interactive php script like (from terminal):

```
$ php <<CODE
<?php
echo "Hello World\n";
?>
CODE
```

But that shell inline editing (using heredoc) is too precarius to my comprehension in moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> will open up the current line in your terminal editor (should be `nano` by default on Ubuntu). When you save and exit the editor, what you have written within it will be executed as if you'd typed it on the command-line as normal.

If you're using vi-keys on the command-line, then you can access the same thing with `<esc>v`.

You can also use the `fc` builtin to open up the text editor on the *previous* command.

Comment: Also, you can change the default editor by setting it on .bashrc, for example, `export EDITOR="vim"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use VI. Here is a quick and dirty command list. http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html